# Why this coding is not working properly in IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

This code is working correctly in Chrome, but if I run this code in Internet Explorer 11 version its not working properly.

I need otuput at Internet Explorer 11

```css
.cc-selector input{
    margin:0;padding:0;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
}

.cc-selector-2 input{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:999;
}

.visa{background-image:url(s1.jpg);}
.mastercard{background-image:url(s3.jpg);}

.cc-selector-2 input:active +.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:active +.drinkcard-cc{opacity: .9;}
.cc-selector-2 input:checked +.drinkcard-cc, .cc-selector input:checked +.drinkcard-cc{
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    filter: none;
}
.drinkcard-cc{
    cursor:pointer;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;height:70px;
    -webkit-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -moz-transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    transition: all 100ms ease-in;
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
    -moz-filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
    filter: brightness(1.8) grayscale(1) opacity(.7);
}
.drinkcard-cc:hover{
    -webkit-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
    -moz-filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
    filter: brightness(1.2) grayscale(.5) opacity(.9);
}

/* Extras */
a:visited{color:#888}
a{color:#444;text-decoration:none;}
p{margin-bottom:.3em;}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="cc-selector">
      <input id="visa" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="visa" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"></label>
      <input id="mastercard" type="radio" name="credit-card" value="mastercard" />
      <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard"for="mastercard"></label>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Why is there a `javascript` tag?

Comment: Exactly what does "not working properly" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported? What is the code *supposed* to do?

Comment: can you please define the expected behaviour and the one you get?

Comment: The output in IE looks very similar to the output in other browsers, in that there is not much to see.

Comment: If i run this code in google chrome its correctly run. If i click a image its change color. But run this code in internet explorer 11 color not change for image..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to the filter property, it is not supported in Internet Explorer 11, you could check the [CSS filter Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_filter.asp).

As an alternative workaround, you could try to use the following code:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #visa,#mastercard {
            display: none;
        }
            #visa + label > img {
                background-image: url(../Images/Image1.jpg);
                width: 500px;
                height: 300px;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 16px;
                opacity: 0.2;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
            #mastercard + label > img {
                background-image: url(../Images/Image2.jpg);
                width: 500px;
                height: 300px;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                font-size: 16px;
                opacity: 0.2;
                transition: 0.3s;
            }
                #visa + label > img:hover, #mastercard + label > img:hover {
                    opacity: 1
                }
            #visa:checked + label > img, #mastercard:checked + label > img {
                opacity: 1
            }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox" id="visa" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc visa" for="visa"><img src="" id="lbl_visa" /></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="mastercard" />
    <label class="drinkcard-cc mastercard" for="mastercard"><img src="" id="lbl_mastercard" /></label>
</body>
```

The result as below:

[image]

Comment: Its work. But i need output like, if i click a second image ,opacity of first image will be 0.2. Like if i click the first image opacity of second image will be 0.2.